# how to get only the value of textfield into variable

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent, graphic

Hello I am trying to draw diagonal lines in Java and this won't work like it should..

the "value" variable is beeing updated in a for loop each time but it gets the next value

for example if i insert a 1 i get this in my console with a system.out.println(value):

> 2
>   4
>   8
>   16
>   32
>   64
>   128
>   256
>   512
>   1024
>   2048
>   4096
>   8192
>   16384
>   32768
>   65536
>   131072
>   262144
>   524288
>   1048576
>   2097152
>   4194304

but the variable "value" has to contain the value i insert.. the code i use for this you can find below

```
DrawLines line = new DrawLines();
int value = 0;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = getHeight() - (getHeight() / 2);

    for(int aantalLines = 0; aantalLines < 10; aantalLines++ ) {
        line.drawLines(g, xPos, yPos + value, getWidth(), getHeight() - value );
        value += value;
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(aantalLines);
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {
        value = Integer.parseInt(tussenRuimte.getText());
        repaint();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number Format Error: Vul alles goed in s.v.p");
    }

}
```

the problem is that it doesn't work like this.. can someone explain what i do wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why modifying the value of `value` while you already have a loop variable:

```
for(int aantalLines = 0; aantalLines < 10; aantalLines++ ) {
  line.drawLines(g, xPos,       yPos +        ((aantalLines + 1) * value), 
                    getWidth(), getHeight() - ((aantalLines + 1) * value) );
}
```

which should come down to what @Hovercraft already suggested.

If none of those solutions help, you probably have a problem somewhere else.

Note: do not alter state in the `paint`, `paintComponent`, ... methods. You have no control over how many times and when they are invoked

Comment: @Reshad by not adjusting the `value` variable in your `paintComponent` method. Otherwise, the next time the `paintComponent` is triggered it will still contain the value from the previous method call, and no longer the value retrieved from the user input.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the value of `value` from within the paintComponent method. Instead, copy it into another variable local to the paintComponent method, and then use and change *that* variable. This way, every time `paintComponent(...)` is called, it doesn't re-set the int held by value.

For example,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = getHeight() - (getHeight() / 2);
    int localValue = value;

    for(int aantalLines = 0; aantalLines < 10; aantalLines++ ) {
        line.drawLines(g, xPos, yPos + localValue, getWidth(), getHeight() - localValue );
        localValue += localValue;
        // System.out.println(value);
        // System.out.println(aantalLines);
    }
}
```

Comment: even with this changes I get the same result.. it seems it keeps doing a value * 2 the whole time. i should do something like localValue += Integer.ParseInt(textfield.getText()); so that the value is the same..